# Can't attach ball particles to object

Tags: node-editor, particles

How can you make these balls on the model?

I've just started getting acquainted with nodes. I have already searched for enough information on YouTube, but most of the videos are old and some nodes are no longer there.  I tried to repeat it [Youtube example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyll9wg9fT8) , but due to the difference in versions, it was impossible.

I also tried to rely on the video on the use of the "magnet", but it does not focus on that part of the model, but I would like to cover the entire or precisely selected area. can someone explain to me how this can be done?

the particle-hair system I have already tried and no result is obtained (v 3.0.1)

[image: image example]

Answer (score 0):

[image]
add the shape "monkey",
add the balls you have to the collection"instance",
then create a Geometry Nodes on monkey.